# Dropdownlist with the same ID

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdownlist with the same ID, jquery is making the same ID and I can access separately... Here is the site www.webbiz.hol.es The Select Region and the Select City I want the Select Region Dropdown when is open to be in the right side and the Select City when is open to the left side... but I can access separately because they have the same id and class.

Here is image with what I want: http://elod.zillmann.ro/pic.jpg

Comment: No 2 elements should have the same ID. If they have, don't try and work around it - just correct it. Show us the code which generates these dropdownlists. I'm assuming they're dynamic - otherwise it's simply a case of changing the markup.

Comment: Don't they have different IDs? I can see `sRegion` and `sCity` (at least on the select-tag).

Answer (score 0):

No HTML version, no XML version and no XHTML version allow you to have more than one element with the same `id` attribute. It's `id` after all. Identification. **Unique** id.

If you want more than one element to share something in common use `class="..."` attribute or `data-*="..."` attributes (where `*` is any string)

Comment: It will 'allow' it (i.e. it wouldn't break a build or error in the same way duplicate ID values might on the server). It's just against convention, best practice, and completely contradicts the purpose of an identifier.

Comment: It's not against convention, it's against markup language and standards. It's not syntax error, but still it's and error. More semantic I think? However we call it, the thing is: "You shall never use the same id twice" :P

Answer (score 0):

When dropdown are created using jquery at that time you might be having a for loop in which dropdown code is written, in that loop write id as id="someID"+i, this i gets value from loop, in this way different id would be assigned.